# The meaning of the word 'fits' in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> A 45-year-old man complains of cough **ﬁts** and tickling in his
>   nasopharynx.

What does '[fits](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fit) mean in this context?

I found many choices in the dictionary and I'm not sure which of them fits to this phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fairly explicit in the dictionary you link to.

> 2. COUNTABLE NOUN
>      If you have a fit of coughing or laughter, you suddenly start coughing or laughing in an uncontrollable way.

From the syntax the word must be a countable noun, and this is the only definition that mentions coughing.

Comment: If it's an adjective,  so what is the letter s for?

Comment: It's a noun. a countable noun. The s forms the plural

Comment: I see.  Thank you!

Comment: sneezing fits are common, too. Also,fits of anger.

Comment: As far as I know, it is normally or at least much more commonly *coughing fits,* not *cough fits.* That is a long list of definitions in the dictionary entry you linked to. It also includes: 
**fit**
uncontrollable movements or emotions
(fɪt  )
Word forms: plural fits 
1. COUNTABLE NOUN
If someone has a fit they suddenly lose consciousness and their body makes uncontrollable movements.
*About two in every five epileptic fits occur during sleep.
Once a fit has started there is nothing you can do to stop it.*
Synonyms: seizure, attack, bout, spasm